# Does there exist such a thing as mini-scaffold?

Tags: furniture, construction

I'm looking to create an anti-RSI workstation.

Something like:

[image]

*(only that particular one happens to be a scam called NEThrone)*

Only what I have in mind is hacking together something using maybe a car seat, an adjustable monitor arm, and some kind of scaffolding rig.

I've used scaffolding in the past, and you can build pretty much any structure with just 2 parts: pipes and clamps.

[image]

However, scaffolding is heavy duty, designed to support thousands of kilos. It's going to be very clumsy working with this.

I'm wondering whether there exists some lightweight alternative. Maybe tubes that are a quarter the diameter.

So my question is specifically this: does such a thing exist?

I would imagine people would use something like this to build home-gyms.

PS If anyone can suggest some online community that may be appropriate for enquiring about this project, I would be very grateful. It seems to be off topic everywhere. But this SE site is designed for people who are building their own solutions -- maybe someone can suggest something?

Answer (score 4):

For a professional system, [Kee Klamps](https://www.keesafety.com/products/kee_klamp) might be what you are looking for:

[image]

For more DIY accessibility, black pipe is a likely candidate:

[image]

Comment: mm yes, https://keesystems.com/store/fittings/kee-klamp.html -- this looks very promising, no jagged edges, much more appropriate gauge tubes, ~$10 per fitting looks doable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to look at Stage Brackets, specifically the cheaper stuff, since this stuff can get expensive. 
Possible Clamps from [this](http://www.rosebrand.com/subcategory561/pipe-tube.aspx?sid=KAPYPmn%2FrVi3T7jTfcOfgwUzUfnQZ5WQ5iZVqawiCCF5uX3z7d5aJA%3D%3D) website (have a look on the site for the full range)

Also, you could try the [Rigging Warehouse](http://www.riggingwarehouse.com/products/RIGHARD01/RIGHARD01@@2e18.aspx?category=Pipe%20Clamps) 
I like the look of these pipe locks [image]

[Lastly lighting](http://www.lighting-effect.com/index.php?manufacturers_id=7&page=1&sort=7a) effect is good on pric

Looks really interesting though. But I must say. that you could actually get a welding shop to weld you up most of this structure for a lot cheaper than the price of some of these clamps!.

Answer (score 0):

Light weight and very expensive; percussionist's rack hardware: ([gibraltarhardware.com](http://www.gibraltarhardware.com/?fa=partsmain&curcat=1&bnd=11&cid=113))

[image: http://www.musik-produktiv.com/gibraltar-road-series-gcs-450c.html]

The one pictured is probably steel tube and the horizontal bars do have a little bit of a curve, but not like in your picture. I had one that was square, stright and made out of aluminum. You could look into boat canopy hardware (also expensive).

---

For everyone else, yes they make cute little scaffolds, I recommend owning one or more of the following: (both of which fold up and will fit in your trunk)

[image: http://www.zoro.com/i/G5214036/?utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Google_Shopping_Feed&gclid=CjwKEAiArqKmBRCOj_qfmuqinnYSJAAkAYwG5enS162jvhIL7kQREoSMkkw8KpxhQFEo0UgC_3qjRRoCtrHw_wcB]

[image: http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/tools/ladders/scaffolding/nu-wave-4-ft-step-up-workstand-su-4?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CjwKEAiArqKmBRCOj_qfmuqinnYSJAAkAYwG4oSjivHo_2qVX32aOphe_mr7SGManjAqJYWJqsJqzRoCOSnw_wcB]